# my input file date format changes on daily basis

Tags: html, regex, csv, perl, opendir

I need help please, my `$inputfile` changes on daily basis which gets generated and store under `/tmp` directory. File format date as follows.

```
/tmp
570572 Sep 13 21:02 sessions_record_2021-09-13_210052.csv
570788 Sep 14 09:01 sessions_record_2021-09-14_090041.csv
```

I'm not sure how to pick it up as an input file instead of hardcoded in my script

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Tie::Array::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;
use Date::Parse;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $hours = 1;
my $timenow = time;
my $inputfile = "sessions_record_2021-09-14_090041.csv";

tie my @sessions_record, 'Tie::Array::CSV', $inputfile, {
   tie_file => { recsep => "\r\n" },
   text_csv => { binary => 1 }
};

tie my @incidentidlist, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'incidentidlist.csv';

@incidentidlist = map {
   ([$$_[4] =~ /\A([^\s]+)/, $$_[4], $$_[18], ($timenow -
str2time($$_[18])) / 60 / 60])
} grep { 
   $$_[0] =~ /^ServiceINC/ && ($timenow - str2time($$_[18])) / 60 / 60 > $hours 
} @sessions_record;
```

Comment: Read the folder, filter the files that have the right naming pattern (i.e. `/^sessions_record_`) and possibly today's date in the name, and open the most recent one of these.

Comment: @simbabque May be simpler to just use a glob: `my @files = </tmp/sessions_record*>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl [sort](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort) function on [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob) will produce sorted array and you interested in last element which can be addressed with index `-1`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $in_file = (sort glob('/tmp/sessions_record_*.csv'))[-1];

say $in_file;
```

If you interested in *today's* file [localtime](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime) can be an assistance to form a filename `$fname`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($mask,$fname);
my($mday,$mon,$year) = (localtime)[3..5];

$year  += 1900;
$mon   += 1;
$mask   = sprintf('/tmp/sessions_record_%4d-%02d-%02d_*.csv', $year, $mon, $mday);
$fname  = (glob($mask))[0];

say 'File: ' . $fname;
say '-' x 45;

open my $fh, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname";

print while <$fh>;

close $fh;
```

Comment: You could save a little trouble with:
`use POSIX 'strftime';`
`$mask = strftime('/tmp/sessions_record_%Y-%m-%d_*.csv', localtime);`

Comment: Thanks @JimDavis - excellent this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use `opendir` to open a directory and `readdir` to read it.  For each file accessed you can check if it has the correct format (as per simbabque's comment) and add it to an array.

Then you can sort your array.

Due to the naming convention the latest file will always sort as the 'largest' value in your sort.

You can red more about sorting (if you need to) at https://www.perltutorial.org/perl-sort/